# What to call the executor of an action?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

I can't find the right word to describe the object that performs an activity/action.

- *Doer*
- *Executor*
- *Performer*
- *Actor*

The term is to be used in an application where you may choose an "object" (from a list), and then retrieve its activities.

So what should I call the "object"?

Context:
The "object" may be anyone or anything which is to do certain activities. Think of a worklog where you'd like to log activities that has been done. Given the object type, you'd might have a different set of activities to log.

Object (1. line support member)
Activities { Create ticket, Assign ticket, Notify customer, Close ticket}

Object (Purchasing employee)
Activities { Receive order, Confirm Order, Ship Order}

Comment: Can you provide more context? What are the "objects" and what are they "performing"? Is this a domain-specific application (scientific, sociological) or general use application?

Comment: It's very difficult to know what word to suggest when we have no idea what kind of object you're talking about (a robot, an *.exe program, an animated monster) or what kind of action the action-taker performs (murder, solving math problems, erasing files). In any case, unless you're talking about last wills and testaments or operating a guillotine, **executor** is not an option. _Executive_ might fit, might not. **Enabler** and **operator** are other possibilities. But without a context, we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: Maybe "Controller"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we might just stick to Performer

Answer (score 7):

One option, which shares its etymology with *action*, is *agent*. Both come fundamentally from the Latin *agere* meaning *to do*.

Comment: This would be my choice. If however *Agent* has another use in this context (which appears to be quite possible) I'd go with *Executant*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[actuator](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/actuator)*

> One that activates, especially a device responsible for actuating a mechanical device, such as one connected to a computer by a sensor link.